# Miles J Cakephp Forum plugin - Some times error "Class 'ForumAppController' not found "

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, forum

I integrated Miles johnson **Cakephp Forum Plugin** from http://milesj.me/blog/read/changelog-forum-3.1. in My project (cakephp 2.0). I followed his documentation.

I integrated successfully. Its working fine but some times when i access my projects users controllers then it throws the following error

```
Fatal error: Class 'ForumAppController' not found in /var/www/projectname/app/Plugin/Forum/Controller/UsersController.php on line 11
```

If i refresh many times then it will work

From Forum plugin I am trying to access users controller of my project and not to forum plugins users controller

Comment: Try asking the author, maybe by raising an issue on the github repo for this script.

Comment: yes sure . Already i send an email to him

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added the following line in Plugins Users controller as per Author answer:

```
App::uses('ForumAppController', 'Forum.Controller');
```